# Is it bad practice to use inline css in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, css

I am new in css. My project is `Layout Manager`. Most of the time I use `inline css`. When I showed my project to the project head, he said to reduce inline css.

Is inline css really bad for project? Please help to clear my vision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inline CSS is bad, period. It does not matter which framework you're using. In addition to bloating the document (and *potentially* slowing load time), it also makes it a lot harder to figure out where the heck values are being set -- as a general rule HTML is dynamic and CSS rarely is. This means if you want to change a style value, you are probably looking at one, flat CSS file, instead of a potentially massive codebase.

Comment: It is not that simple, it is not always the worst thing using inline css. Sometimes you just need to change color for single line of text and you can't or don't want to change whole stylesheets file. And if you are using good webdeveloping tools (like firebug) you can easily find out where the stylesheets are being set.

Comment: @shaggy At that point I think you're more talking "necessary evil" than "good". I've done that and hated it, but sometimes requirements are requirements and we've no choice.

Comment: @cwallenpoole It is not necessary evil, It's normal practice and if you are not overusing inline styles, everything should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

> I am new in css

No, you are new to wweb programming. You can not say you did HTML etc. without touching CSS at all ;)

> My project is Layout Manager

Which tells us nothing.

> Is inline css really bad for project?

no, it has zero implications for your project.

It normally is a maintenance problem (not if auto generated). It's main issue is waste of bandwidth because inline CSS have to be on every page instead of being on a seaprate file loaded only once for all pages in the site. Dependingon size and traffic this can be SIGNIFICANT.

Answer (score 1):

the reasons why should avoid inlines css

a) [**Separation of concerns**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) - your markup should contain only markup code and all you rhutehr hunky dory code should be in separate files like js and css.One of the main goals of CSS is to remove the design elements from the HTML and place them in another location for the designer to maintain. That means that a designer doesn't have to also be the content developer to maintain the look of the Web site.

b) **Caching of Files** when you have your js and css in separate files the browsers starts caching this till something has changed on the server and this means less data transmitted between the server and the client thus saving up on b/w and the page loading faster for your viewers..

c)**Make maintenance easy**
  One of the most forgotten elements of Web design is the maintenance. Things change - from the look of your site to the content and links within it. And having your CSS in a central place makes it that much easier to maintain.

d)**Keep your site accessibile**
  Using CSS styles can keep your site more accessible both to disabled people and to robots like search engines.

e)**Your site will stay current longer**
   By using best practices with your CSS, you're using standards that have been proven to work and remain flexible as the Web design environment changes.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the style will be loaded before the page loads.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="anyClass">Hello</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But if we use the following, browser will be interrupted during parsing every specific style defined inline the style attribute, so this will slowdown load-time:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="height: 70px;">Hello</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, placing the style in a separate style-sheet will help you reusing the styles and maintenance of the code will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Inline CSS is bad or good depending on what you will achieve in the project in the future.

For example take this two general cases:

If the css that you define inline will be used again then using inline is bad, just add it to a css file and reuse it every time you need in the future.

If the inline you are using is an one time exception then it is a good solution and there is no point in overcomplicating design by placing it in a separate css file.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to separate HTML, css and javascript in separate files and because you are new to web programming, you can make this practice easily from the beginning.

The disadvantages of inline CSS are:

- Significant usage of bandwidth.
- Cannot use a style on multiple documents.
- Cannot implement pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes in inline styles.
- Cannot create neat and clean HTML with inline css.